# next_permutation problem c++

Tags: c++, stl, permutation

While using this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<line; i++) {
    next_permutation(nums, nums+N);
    if(DEBUG) {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            cout << nums[j] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this output: `-1076591092_1_2_4_3_-1076591092_1_3_2_4_`

Int his case, line would be 3, and N is 5;
Thanks!

Comment: How is `nums` defined and initialised?

Comment: you might want `#ifdef _DEBUG` instead

Comment: Without some more context I don't think we can help.  This seems like either an uninitialized variable or memory corruption, but I can't tell which without more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to poor memory management.

Answer (score 2):

`[-1076591092, 1, 3, 2, 4]` is the next permutation after `[-1076591092, 1, 2, 4, 3]`, according to [definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/).